# Python script that writes a csv to Dropbox works locally, but fails when I run it on AWS EC2

Tags: python, pandas, csv, amazon-ec2, dropbox

I have a python script that - after much data processing - writes a ".csv" file to my Dropbox (it saves a pandas df directly to Dropbox, without storing it locally first). When I run the code on my local machine, the program successfully creates the file as I intended. However, when I run the same code on Amazon's EC2 server, the file that is created is completely unintelligible.

Here is a simplified version of the problem:

```
import io
import dropbox
import pandas as pd

DBX = dropbox.Dropbox('My_Dropbox_Token')

df = pd.DataFrame([range(5), list("ABCDE")])

with io.BytesIO() as stream:

    with pd.ExcelWriter(stream) as writer:
        df.to_excel(writer)
        writer.save()

    stream.seek(0)

    DBX.files_upload(stream.getvalue(), "/test.csv", mode=dropbox.files.WriteMode.overwrite)
```

When I run this code on my local machine, the dataframe appears on my dropbox as a .csv file normally. Running the same code on EC2, I get no errors, but the .csv that is created is non-sensical.

[Image of what the CSV from EC2 looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwZeD.png)

How do I fix this so that the .csv file from EC2 makes sense?

OBS: I encounter the same problem regardless of whether I keep the file name as "/test.csv" or "/test.xlsx"

Comment: You're running into some encoding-errors. Make sure that the data and the mode of writing is using the same encoding.

Comment: As an example, if I run the following code: `"abcåäö".encode("utf-8").decode("Latin-1")`, the output will be `'abcÃ¥Ã¤Ã¶'`

Comment: @HampusLarsson Thanks for the quick feedback. But why do I not run into the encoding problem that you described when I run it on my local machine?

Comment: It could be based on a lot of stuff, but most probably it has to do with the language of the operating system. Because I don't know how your data is structured, I cannot help on that front, but you could try to `decode` the string locally. If it looks good on your side, and it's based on the same data, then it should be writing it correctly to your file.

Comment: @HampusLarsson, that helps a lot! I am still struggling to decode it though. Do I just use:
```pd.read_csv(filename, encoding = 'utf-8')```
and then I keep trying different conventions for encoding?

What would you advise?

Comment: As a follow-up, I have tried using ```chardet``` to determine the encoding of the csv file. I get weird results:

```{'encoding': None, 'confidence': 0.0, 'language': None}```

Any ideas?